# MOSS All Groups does not show pagination when more than 100 groups returned

Tags: moss, wss

When I go to `/_layouts/groups.aspx` in my site collection, I only see the first 100 groups.  There is no pagination control visible.  How do I correct this, to work with more than just the first 100 groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also modify this view through the standard UI, rather than using code if you need to:

1. Browse to "http://***<site collection url>***/_catalogs/users/AllGroups.aspx"
2. Site Actions-> Edit Page
3. Modify the List View web part
4. Under Selected View click the "Edit the current view" link.
5. You can now edit the view settings like any other in SharePoint.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Where were you two years ago? ;-)

Comment: :) Sorry, I stumbed across the post when looking for an answer to this question myself and thought there had to be an easier way. So posted the above for other people in my shoes.

Answer (score 1):

That list is a sharepoint internal list which cannot be accessed through the API and must be hit by utilizing the object model.

Assuming you're familiar with the SharePoint API,

You need to access your site programmatically
then access the users and groups list, then access the default view on it, and set it's paging property to true.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //Access the site
  using (SPSite _site = new SPSite("http://myurlwithport:800"))
  {
    //Substitute the appropriate web if it is not the root
    using (SPWeb _web = _site.RootWeb)
    {
      // This is always the name of the users list
      SPList userList = _web.Lists["User Information List"];

      //This is the view that is causing you trouble
      SPView allGroupsView = userList.Views["All Groups"];

      //Set this value to true if it is false.
      Console.WriteLine(allGroupsView.Paged);

      //Set this value to whatever you want if you don't want paging
      Console.WriteLine(allGroupsView.RowLimit);                   

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this does it for ye.

**EDIT**

Based on OP comments

There is a RowLimit property that you can change instead if you want.

I've added it into the code provided.

Comment: I think it sucks that there is no way to work with more than 100 groups in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share some additional clarification to Michael M's suggestion on updating the "AllGroups.aspx".

Initially, I used a regular Site Collection admin account to access the 
"http:///_catalogs/users/AllGroups.asp" page and got access denied.

I then used another Site Collection admin account who's also in the Windows admin group for the SP server and still got access denied.

Finally, I used the SharePoint 2010 Farm admin account that we used to setup the Web App/App Pool, and that finally gave me access to the page.